# Google Custom Search Engine - Range

Tags: google-search-console, google-custom-search

Using Google Custom Search Engine for our events pages. Trying to have the search result only return upcoming events.

Added a PageMap block in the head - wrapped in `<!--` and `-->`

```
  <PageMap>
    <DataObject type="date">
      <Attribute name="eventends" value="20170902"/>
    </DataObject>
  </PageMap>
```

Google custom search block -

```
<gcse:search sort_by="date-eventends:r:20170725:20190101">
</gcse:search>
```

Focused on google docs -
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#structured_search_element

Particularly -

"The sort option also enables the Restrict by Range feature. For example a site like SignOnSanDiego might enable users to search for articles published between August 25 and September 9 in 2010. To implement this, you can set the sort options to `date-sdate:r:20100825:20100907`".

The search results pull back all events that meet the search term - no filter occurring.

---

Have used Google Search Engine to reindex individual pages - the pagemap tag is recognized and been indexed.